# Scatter plot of points from several groups with legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I need to make a scatter plot of two variables in a data frame. The observations come from three groups, so I want to use three different colors. I also want to include a legend on the plot. Here is a small example.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'y': [3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 8], 'grp': ['a','a','b','a','c','b','c']}
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I learned that if each group is plotted separately, I can get what I need.

```
x1 = data.loc[data['grp'] == 'a', 'x']
y1 = data.loc[data['grp'] == 'a', 'y']
x2 = data.loc[data['grp'] == 'b', 'x']
y2 = data.loc[data['grp'] == 'b', 'y']
x3 = data.loc[data['grp'] == 'c', 'x']
y3 = data.loc[data['grp'] == 'c', 'y']
plt.scatter(x1, y1, label = 'a')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, label = 'b')
plt.scatter(x3, y3, label = 'c')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

This approach seems to be a little inefficient, especially when the number of groups is big. Another approach I found from stackoverflow is the following.

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
values = data['grp'].replace(['a','b','c'], [0, 1, 2])
colors = ListedColormap(['r','b','g'])
scatter = plt.scatter(data['x'], data['y'], c=values, cmap=colors)
plt.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=['a', 'b', 'c'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is easier since you don't have to do each group separately. However, I don't quite understand `handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0]`. Is there an easy and intuitive way of doing this? I have been a R user before and this task can be easily done in `ggplot` where everything seems to be handled automatically. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does my answer address your issue?

Comment: @jared Yes, thank you for your answer! I just accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pandas [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method to split the groups by the `"grp"` column. The plot can be made by looping through groups and plotting them individually.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

d = {"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
     "y": [3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 8], 
     "grp": ["a","a","b","a","c","b","c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for group, data in df.groupby("grp"):
    ax.scatter(data.x, data.y, color=colors[group], label=group)
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

[image]

If you want to use the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) package, then you can use the `scatterplot` function and pass the `"grp"` to the `hue` argument to color them by group.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

plt.close("all")

d = {"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
     "y": [3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 1, 8], 
     "grp": ["a","a","b","a","c","b","c"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
colors = {"a":"r", "b":"g", "c":"b"}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="grp", ax=ax, palette=colors)
fig.show()
```

[image]

If you have a large number of groups, then you probably don't want to specify the colors manually. In that case, don't pass the `color` argument to the matplotlib-only version or the `palette` to the seaborn version.